# Best practice: Phonegap Sencha Touch 2 and saving login datas

Tags: extjs, authentication, cordova, passwords, save

I am looking for an way to save my users login data on the client.

If he enter my app first I ask the server, is my user is still logged in... If yes i change the view to the main menu. If not, I look for the saved datas and log him in automatically.

For this I need to save his data after first login. My question is, what is the best way? I know about Web Storage and local Storage. 
The point is that user password have to be securely encrypted. For that Sencha offers base64, but is that really safe?

How do you handle this topic?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you authenticate your members?

Comment: With username and passwort :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OAuth 2.0` for authentication.
That case it is enough to save an **access token** on their device without saving password.

On the serverside you can control the validity / lifetime of these tokens.

Otherwise you can store data using `LocalStorage` in an easy and convinient way.

To start with Oauth: http://oauth.net/2/ 
or a tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/oauth-2-0-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/

Comment: LocalStorage is not an option because if user cleares all his browser data (I do not mean only the cache!), his saved datas will be lost too... Unfortunately working with tokens is not possible in my case. I really have to save name and password. The point is where to save and how to encrypt the password. Maybe a local sqlite database?